# Cannot call base __init__ in a class created with type()

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I create a class with type as I need to use a variable for the base.
It works fine if I don't provide an `__init__` method, but when I do provide one, I am unable to call the base's `__init__`.

Works:

```
def constructor():
    blah blah
    api = importlib.import_module(xtype)
    mc = type('mc', (api.aclass,), {})
    obj = mv(**args)
    return obj
```

doesn't work, returns "`SystemError: super(): __class__ cell not found`"

```
def constructor():
    blah blah
    api = importlib.import_module(xtype)
    mc = type('mc', (api.aclass,), dict(__init__ = mc__init)
    obj = mc(**args)
    return obj

def mc_init(*args, **kwargs):
    do_some_stuff
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

doesn't work, returns "`Base mc.__init__ not called.`" later at object creation:

```
def constructor():
    global api
    blah blah
    api = importlib.import_module(xtype)
    mc = type('mc', (api.aclass,), dict(__init__ = mc__init)
    obj = mc(**args)
    return obj

def mc_init(*args, **kwargs):
    global api
    do_some_stuff
    api.aclass.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

x = constructor()
```

How can I call the **init** for the base class?

Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you mark answers that satisfy you as being "Accepted" (green check mark). You asked 7 questions, and none of them was accepted; this is unusual. You would motivate people to answer, if they know that they can hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that your `type` calls are working; `bases` should be a tuple (`(api.aclass,)`).  Is this just a typo?

Your `super()` call in (2) won't work as it is outside a class declaration; Python 3 `super` magic is quite complicated and to be honest a little fragile.  You could write `super(mc, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

However, there's no reason for you not to use a proper class declaration here (especially if you don't understand how to use 3-argument `type`); Python is perfectly OK with classes being declared with variable bases:

```
def constructor():
    ...
    api = importlib.import_module(xtype)
    class mc(api.aclass):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    obj = mc(**args)
    return obj
```

Comment: The `super(mc, self)` does not work, it returns: `NameError: global name 'mc' is not defined', but I guess I could make it a global. I had not realised you could use a variable as a base, which worked and solved my